# Fabric tool for android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, proxy, twitter-fabric

Android studio network connection success. Fabric tool error unable to connect to the network. How do I make the proxy settings ?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

java home\jre\lib\net.properties your proxy add.
{`java.net.useSystemProxies=true; http.proxyHost=****; http.proxyPort=****; http.proxyUser=****; http.proxyPassword=****; https.proxyHost=****; https.proxyPort=****; https.proxyUser=****; https.proxyPassword=****;`}
try again. 
Android studio run administrator.